# Find out booking class of past flights

Tags: air-travel, fare-class

Is there a way to find out the booking class of a **past** flight, only having your **name**, **flight number** and **booking reference/ticket number**?

Comment: If you mean you no longer have the ticket/e-ticket, that will probably depend on the airline and/or the channel you booked through. Also, how far back are talking about?

Comment: I was thinking about flights up to 1 year in the past (which usually also is the maximum time to redeem missing flights). Yes, I'm referring to flights where I do not have the information anymore (neither the ticket/boarding pass, nor emails where the fare class is stated). It already seems from your comment and Zach's answer that there is unfortunately no general (online) tool, that can provide this...

Comment: I’m not sure if tools like checkmytrip include past bookings? Also I wonder in what situation you would have the ticket number but not the rest of the info?

Comment: Checkmytrip does not show the booking class (atleast in some cases). It is possible to have the ticket number but no booking class, for example, the boarding passes in Apple Wallet usually also contain the respective ticket number, but not necessarily the booking class.

Comment: Do you have the emails?

Comment: Not for all flights. I'm also asking this as a more general question "Is it possible obtain X with only Y, Z and ..."

Comment: Will the airline’s website allow you to print another receipt or ticket?  Since it will have a date in the past, there’s little risk that you will use it to actually go anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The airline may have a mechanism to request a receipt after you travel. United, for example, has [a form you can fill out](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/reservation/flight/receipt/past.aspx) and they'll send you back a receipt within two weeks. If your airline doesn't have an online form for this, you can contact them and ask if there is any such process. You might also have a copy in your email if you booked the tickets yourself.

Another place to look is your frequent flyer account, if you have one. Since mileage earning sometimes depends on the booking class, it may be displayed on your statement. I know that United shows it on their statements (see [this example](http://10xtravel.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/MileagePlusX7.png), which lists the flight number and G-class), as does Ethiad (see [this example](https://bartlapers.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/etihad-guest-miles-activity.jpg), which lists the booking class after the / for each flight).